# Similar String comparison fails

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio

I am trying the following code in Android Studio. When Debugging, I find out that even when Value of variable B is "(" my if statement does not execute and hovering over it, it shows it is false (please refer to image).
The value of ScreenText in this case is "6(".

Any help is appreciated.

.[image]

Comment: Check [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Please post code, not screenshots of code.

Answer (score 2):

You should compare strings with the `.equals()` method. In this case, and to prevent a null pointer exception in case that your B variable is null, you should do so like this:

```
if("(".equals(B)) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Luis and YoungHobbit :)

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator is used for reference comparison, to check whether two object have the same reference.

You want to compare two `String`s, use the `boolean equals(String)` method.

```
if( "(".equals(B)) {
// your logic
}
```

Here comparing `B` with `"("` constant does not require you to make `null` checks.

Answer (score 0):

I think a more generic way to compare strings in Android is:

```
TextUtils.equals(B, "(");
```

And by the way, in your code

```
String.valueOf(c).toString();
```

toString() is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the value or contents of two strings then use `.equals()`.

```
if(string.equals("(")){
    //Enter your code
}
```

But if you want to check that two object points to same reference then use `==`